# Can you identify this 1x2 brick with groves going opposite directions on each side?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

There are about 20 of these bricks in the set. Nothing else that stands out as unique. This may be a long shot.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]
*[Part #2877 Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Grille (Flutes).](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2877&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Grille%20(Flutes)&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)*